# Why are undeclared @variables nil in html.erb and not a NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

If an **html.erb** file is rendered **without** variables assigned in a controller (e.g. `@user = params["user_name"] )` then why does it view `@user` as `nil` instead of throwing a `NameError: undefined local variable`.

For Example:

```
<%= render partial: "greeting", locals: { user: @user } if @user %>
```

This will render the greeting if a controller passes it a `@user`, but if the page is rendered for the first time and the user hasn't entered their username yet the greeting will simply not be there, instead of causing an error.  It seems to me that `@user` would never be declared in the local scope the **html.erb** is executing in, so it should cause the error.

What's happening here?  Perhaps the `@` is somehow preprocessed to mean treat the variable as a symbol and use that as the key in a `params` hash and return the result?

Answer (score 5):

Uninitialized instance variables (`@...`) evaluate to `nil`. You can still check if an instance variable has been assigned (including assignment to `nil`) by using the `defined?` method:

```
[1] pry(main)> defined? @test
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> @test = nil
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> defined? @test
=> "instance-variable"
```

Comment: So it's a ruby language thing not a rails thing?

Comment: @TPE Yep, it's a property of the Ruby language.

Comment: To further `August`'s contribution, you have to appreciate that as Ruby is [Object-Orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), it treats every "variable" as an `object`, including those which are yet to be defined. 

This means that if you haven't declared the variable, instead of throwing a "not declared" error, like most other languages, Ruby actually assigns the value to the `NilClass` - meaning it's there, just doesn't have any data

Comment: @RichPeck: Variables are one of the very few things which are *not* objects in Ruby.

Comment: @TPE: Rails is just a Ruby library like any other. It cannot change the evaluation semantics of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

> then why does it view `@user` as `nil` instead of throwing a `NameError: undefined local variable`.

Well, it's not a local variable, it's an instance variable.

But even local variables behave the same way:

```
if false
  local_var = 42 # needed so Ruby knows `local_var` isn't a method call
end

local_var
# => nil

@instance_variable
# => nil

$global_variable
# => nil
```

But strangely:

```
Constant
# NameError: uninitialized constant Constant

@@class_variable
# NameError: uninitialized class variable @@class_variable in Object
```